# Being reported for "Bad behaviour"?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm pretty new to GTA Online, I've only played it a few times, but I was wandering around my own house and suddenly got a notification that another player had reported me for "bad behaviour". I have no idea what this means, or how I got it.

I don't have a microphone, I haven't sent any bad messages to people. I've never quit out of any missions early, either.

I WAS continuously targeted by a player or two in the "Lobby" (i.e. the map), and every time I respawned they would attack me. But that was all fun. Eventually I got my revenge and blew them and their car up with a bomb.

Sometime after that, I got "reported" by another player.

I have no idea if it's related to my revenge or not. Is there any reason why I would be reported by another player? Can anyone tell me what this means in real terms?

Comment: I assume that people can report you for any reason they like, even just to troll people. They may have thought you were being a bad sport hiding in your house, they may have thought your gamertag was stupid, they may have been on crack and hit the wrong button on your profile. I wouldn't worry about it, you're unlikely to notice any negative effects unless it happens a lot.

Comment: this sounds just like league of legends

Comment: You probably one upped the guy with that revenge and he couldn't take it... people like that need to stop playing video games if they cant take getting beat haha

Comment: Isn't bad behaviour the entire point of the game?

Comment: Based on my limited time with GTA Online, and what little I've read about it, blowing up another player's car is considered disrespectful. Which strikes me as odd, all things considered. That could've been the reason for the report, albeit a terrible one.

Comment: I've read that blowing up other people's vehicles is "Bad Form", too. It seems bizarre given that a) The owner can purchase insurance, b) Nobody is forcing them to ride around the map in it, and c) This is GTA! Very confusing. (And in this case, the person was trying to kill me from inside their car, and had blown up many of my vehicles.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to stop people from reporting you for whatever reason they want.

Even if you get ganged up on and retaliate, this can still be construed as bad behavior.

This kind of thing is not limited to GTA. As Philipp Sander pointed out in the comment section, it's extremely prevalent in the League of Legends community as well.

Players will report you for any number of reasons, one of which is that they just felt like it at the time.

Comment: Rule #1 of any online interaction.  People will be horrible and hate you for nothing.

Comment: @BammaHamma That's why I only play with friends and I always ask the nice people I run into to play with me. There is nothing worse than having people flame you for no reason.

Comment: I mostly just stay away from online games altogether.  That's getting real hard these days...

Comment: Another way to deal with trolls is to give them their own medicine, I'm not saying stoop to their level and report them back but just mess with them in a lot of little ways. It's fun to see twelve year old trolls have a break down.

Comment: I find ignoring people is the best. The more you feed the beasts, the more they will attack.

Comment: Playing any game with people you can't reach across and slap in the mouth will always lead to this sadly. There's a really bad side of the gaming community that are the loudest at times. I just ignore all of them and leave them to their petty sad little reports and moaning.

Comment: @RossC your assumption that playing same-couch multiplayer is any different is questionable...  I have as a...  "friend" one of the people who *tries* to moderate his behavior a little in "public" (read:  randoms online), but doesn't hold back at all when in the room with friends.

Comment: @gatherer818 sadly I know exactly what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. But i have sent a message to rockstar before about bad sport status. Its just there to let other players know to be weary of you. And as far as banning. Giving enough complaints they may suspend your rockstar access pending an investigation, but even then its not long unless its serious like modding. If nothing turns up though they usualy send you an email stating our bad and maybe some free cash or something for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry about what?